# Как сделать линию на css и html

Tags: html, css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу сделать вот эту линию которая опоясывает форму.

HTML:

```
<div class="request">
        <p>Оставьте заявку сейчас и получите дизайн интерьера 25кв<sup>2</sup> бесплатно!*</p>
        <form action="" method="POST">
            <div class="wrapForm wrapInput">
                <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Ваше имя" class="fieldInput">
                <input type="text" name="e-mail" placeholder="e-mail" class="fieldInput">
                <input type="phone" name="phone" placeholder="Номер телефона" class="fieldInput">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapForm wrapButton">
                <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Оставить заявку!" class="submit">
            </div>
        </form>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header .request {
    position: relative;
    max-width: 956px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 33px;
}


header .request::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 68px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 77px;
    border: 2px solid grey;
    z-index: -1;
}

header .request p {
    color: white;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 22px;
    text-align: center;
}

header .request p:last-child {
    font-size: 16px;
}

header form, .wrapForm {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: 40px;
    max-width: 919px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    z-index: 3;
}

header .wrapForm {
    background-color: transparent;
    margin: 0;
}

header .wrapButton {
    width: 240px;
}
```

Получается вот это:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
* { margin: 0; padding: 0; box-sizing: border-box; }

body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.frame {
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid black;
  border-right: 1px solid black;
}

form {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.row:first-child {
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.row:last-child {
  transform: translateY(50%);
}

.row::after,
.row::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 1px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  background-color: black;
}

input {
  width: 100px;
  height: 30px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 0 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="frame">
  <form>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
      <input type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="">
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```